# How can I show additional DNS information to nslookup -type=any?

Tags: bash, dns

When I type the `nslookup`  with the  `-type=any domain.com ns1.server.com`, 
I get most of the records of domain.com. However, other records like CNAME associated with www.domain.com are not listed. So, I was wondering if there is an alternative command that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **dig** command for this :

> dig -t  ANY example.com +noall +answer

Please check man page for more information.

From man dig :

**ANY** - view all DNS record types

**-t** - option sets the query type to type

**+noall** - Set or clear all display flags.

**+noanswer** -  Display [do not display] the answer section of a reply. The default is to display it.